# Asking questions for feedback on your own programming techniques

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I worked on an algorithm as part of my research back when I was doing a thesis and am curious how it would be received by the programming community at large (I already know how it was received academically). Also, in the same question, I'd like to see differing opinions/options to solving the same problem I attempted to solve.

I know the "can I ask my own question and answer" dilemma has been visited before, but this is a bit different as I'm acknowledging right away that there's more than one way to do it, while also attempting to get feedback/thoughts on my current approach.

If I asked a question about the general domain (in this case hierarchical pathfinding), and provided my own technique as an answer in addition to hoping for other differing techniques as answers, is this permissible? I've already done lots of background research on the topic in the traditional channels, but I'm curious to see how this would work out in the Stack Overflow setting.

Comment: I guess an extension to the question could be "can SO be a valid place for research to take place as it grows over time?"

Answer (score 5):

Post the question first and leave it a few days before posting your answer.

This will give people time to come up with their own solutions without reference to yours.

You can then post your own solution and people can then vote on it's worth relative to the other answers.

How you'd phrase your question though - I can't help you there ;)

Comment: Thanks, I think that's a pragmatic approach.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a valid question. I would set it to Community wiki though.

Comment: Not a bad idea, since I'm not looking for any rep gain or anything like that in terms of the question. I feel that the answers should probably still remain normal-mode, though. Not so much for my own, but for the other people who put in the time and thought worth recognition. That makes sense, right?

Comment: I mean, I envision this question (and future ones like it) requiring a decent amount of work to answer. Much more than the "how do I print a string"-type questions, and people are helping my cause out greatly by contributing.

Comment: @Kyle, If that's the case you don't want to make it CW. You may want to make your answer CW though.

Comment: @Brad wouldn't that be the reverse effect? Or am I not understanding how CW works...My understanding was that CW makes it community-editable and stops rep gain, only allowing badges.

Comment: Yes, Kyle, but if you CW your questions, all answers are CW automatically. You don't have an option any more then.

Comment: @John thanks for clearing that up for me.